# Connection pooling in Swing based Application

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, desktop-application, connection-pooling

I have one application in Java Swing.
In which i have used one connection for the application on single database.
But now multiple users are usig that application , so everytime new connection is getting created.
DB is coming very slow in performance;
Can I use connection pooling in Swing based desktop based application.
DB used is SQL server 2000.

Any help appriciated.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Of course you can use a connection pooler in a Swing application.

Comment: Do the Swing application connects to the database directly? Or do they connect to a server-sided application which does the database connection?

Comment: No its a direct DB connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  : can u please explain in which way I can move in connection pooling.Please mension the libraries which I can use..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)

There are many [connection pooling libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/connection-pools) in fact.

Comment: ..but can I use C3P0 libraries for SQL server 2000.

Comment: Yes you can use it with any JDBC compatible RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

http://commons.apache.org/pool/ 
might be also helpful. I actually had the same question for CouchDB here: 
[Connection pool for couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227213/connection-pool-for-couchdb)